# Reporting on Connecting device OS with build number in Citrix ICA Sessions

Tags: windows, powershell, citrix

We're looking to implement some tooling around controlling access to our XenDesktop environment by enforcing host based metrics. One of them is polling the endpoint OS plus build number. We're an on-prem CVAD deployment, with  roughly 5,000 endpoints in a XenDesktop persistent model.

Polling the VDA's themselves, get-brokersession and get-brokermachine show only if it's a Windows, Mac, Linux endpoint connecting in with a ProductID to associate, but no other information. Similarly, the API calls are doing roughly the same thing.

We are coming in externally via Netscaler Gateway, but we're not sure if the Client Build will show in the HTTP(s) requests coming through (SSL not SSL Bridge). Lastly, I've not had much hope in exploring the Monitoring or Site Databases for Citrix connections either.

Searching online, I've not found any good examples other than polling on Client OS but nothing further.

Has anyone solved this or found a means to grab this information?